# Casting object to a child class that extend mother class

Tags: php

I am trying to add a method to a class by extending it and then to cast an object to my child extended class:

```
public class motherClass(){
  public function methodA(){}
}

public class childClass extends motherClass (){
  public function methodB(){}
}


$obj= Method that return an istance of motherClass
$objChild = (childClass) $obj;
$objChild->methodB();
```

Is possible to do this in PHP ?
I need to instaziate the $objChild becouse I want to call some method from childClass in an object that belongs to motherClass.

Comment: I do not really understand what you are trying to achieve. could you clarify?

Comment: This is known as downcasting.  And no, PHP cannot do this.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721949/downcasting-in-php5

Comment: Check out this question and answer, which is pretty similar to what you're asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080217/cast-the-current-object-this-to-a-descendent-class

Comment: Ok, there is a work around? I really need to add some methods to a class by extending it.